# 2 GIT Repos to keep framework up to date and project separate

Tags: php, git, repository

I have googled for a while now, and haven't yet found a good solution to the following problem:

I have a git repository for my own framework, say repo-A, and I have a git repository per project, say repo-B.

Each project utilizes repo-A as core.

This means that in the root dir of the project, there need to be 2 repositories, repo-A, so I can pull framework updates, and repo-B, so I can push the project so my project partners in turn can pull the project updates.

I'm looking for a way to make this work, but haven't found any. Can anyone help me?

Comment: You could use [private composer repositories](https://getcomposer.org/doc/05-repositories.md#using-private-repositories) for your framework and require it on each project's `composer.json`

Comment: yes, but that wouldn't work in this case I believe, since my framework structure looks like:

App (all the php stuffs)
 - Controllers (custom controllers for the project)
 - more framework stuff
Resources 
 - core (framework base views/js/css)
 - admin (part is base template, part is custom)
 - site (main website views/js/css, custom)

since composer requires you to use the autoloader, the structure would differ.

Comment: your framework structure looks like?

Comment: The structure looks similar to the Laravel structure

Comment: That means you could make changes to your framework in a project and that could cause conflict while pulling the updates. Right?

Comment: Yes that could be possible, but if that would make it waaaaaay more complicated, I would give each project a deploy key only, so it would only be pulleable and not pusheable, changes to the framework will need to be made on a different framework dev environment